# Odd ratio changes after adjusting, what does that mean?

Tags: logistic, odds-ratio

I have been using logistic regression to measure the association between two variables. Let us say, we want to test the association between A and B. A is the outcome and B is the exposure. The association between A and B gives me an OR = 5, and it is significant when looking at the p-value.

```
A ~ B
```

Then I want to adjust for C. The association between A and B is still significant, but the OR for that association changed to OR = 4.7.

```
A ~ B + C
```

Later I adjusted for D, and the OR for A and B's association is now changed to OR = 5.3, and it is still significant.

```
A ~ B + C + D
```

My question is, what does this mean? These small changes, the decreasing and increasing of OR after adjusting? How is this interpreted? Maybe it means nothing?

Comment: It means that the observed effect of B on A changes after you take another variable into account. Whether these changes actually mean anything is dependent on your domain knowledge and on a causal model, not on the statistical model. It's also hard to say how much the change matters without the standard errors of the estimates.

Comment: Thanks for answering. What do you exactly mean with SE? I know what SE is superficially.  But how could that help me to interpreted the decreasing/increasing OR?  Like if the SE are big or small? And regarding the first thing you wrote; B, C and D are all known in the literature for having an effect on A. And I want to know if B is contributing the most, to get the outcome. In other words, I want to see if C and D is confounders or interacts on the association between A and B. The association between A and B is still significant when adding C and D, but these small changes confuses me

Comment: @wzbillings Ordinarily we would say it is hard to say whether the change can be *attributed to chance* (in a sense made clear by the mathematical expression of the regression model) without having an estimate of the SEs or their equivalent.  Whether such a change *matters* depends on how the results will be used and the consequences of those uses.